# An attempt to scp a file I can read returns the error, “No such file or directory”

Tags: filesystems, file-transfer, remote-access, file-permissions, scp

I'm trying to [`scp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) (secure copy) a file from a remote server to my local machine. The command I am using is this:

```
scp user@server:/path/to/source/file.gz /path/to/destination
```

But the error I get is this:

```
scp: /path/to/source/file.gz: No such file or directory
```

The “user” in the `scp` command is my username on the server. The command syntax appears fine to me. `ssh` works fine and I can `cd` to the file and it doesn’t seem to be an access control issue?

**EDIT:** Thank you John. I spotted the issue.

`ls` returned this:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 nobody users 168967171 Mar 10  2009 /path/to/source/file.gz
```

So, the file was on a read-only file system and user is able to read it but not `scp`. I just copied the file to a different directory and `chown` it and worked fine. It would be good if someone can explain why this is the case though.

Comment: what does this show? ssh user@server 'ls -l /path/to/source/file.gz'

Comment: As noted, the permissions are OK for reading the file, and are not the issue. You post a mock-up path - perhaps in reality you are trying to use a path with e.g. spaces and don't escape them properly. Give the "real" command instead of the synthetic one so we can spot any such errors.

Comment: Most probably you have mistake in the path. Check if it really should start from `/`, `~` or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

`r` (only) permissions don't indicate a read-only filesystem. They indicate that the *file* is read-only.

The third `r` indicates that anybody can read the file so there shouldn't have been a problem.

The question is what are the permissions for the *parent directory* of this file? However, if they're wrong you should have gotten a permission denied error.

Are there any other conditions which might affect this file's availability such as an NFS mount, etc.?